# Given text file with names, if folder has files with such names - delete it, else make folder with this name

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I was curious to make such thing in windows cmd that is taking source.txt file with such names:

```
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
User6
```

Secondly, I have created the destination folder `F:\Destination` The task is to iterate with source.txt and if a file from this txt exists at the address `F:\Destination`, delete it, if such file does not exist, create a folder with this name.

For example: I have `User1.txt` `User2.txt` and `User3.txt` in `F:\Destination` as a result I need to delete them and create folders `User4` `User5` and `User6`

Here is my script, but sadly it's doing nothing

```
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %G in ("source.txt") do if exist
"Destination\%~G" del "Destination\%~G" if not exist "Destination\%~G" md "Destination\%~G"
```

Looking forward to your suggestions and solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to use the commandline? With PowerShell it would be a simple to create those folders `Get-Content .\source.txt | ForEach-Object { New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_ }` adding the other logic might also be easier/more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some issues:

- The way to reference the `G` variable in a batch file is `%%G`, not `%~G`
- You said that the files in the destination folder are named **User1.txt** etc, but you don't check for **.txt**
- The options in the `for` command don't really do anything now, you can leave those out. In that case, do not quote `source.txt`. See `help for` for details
- The line break between your two lines doesn't help, or is that just the formatting of your question? If so, please fix that. Anyway, it's better to format the code a bit, and use parentheses

Something like this should work:

```
for /F %%G in (source.txt) do (
    if exist "Destination\%%G.txt" del "Destination\%%G.txt" 
) else (
    if not exist "Destination\%%G" md "Destination\%%G"
)
```

Comment: This is somehow correct, but this script creating folder whenever .txt is listed in the F:\Destination or not. Anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question, fixed.